# python module-level executable commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, startup

In python, executable statements (`if`, `while`, `print` etc.) can be placed in the module - without being wrapped inside a function.

In **C++**, I wrap commands inside a function. Only `static` variable initialization can be "executed" IIRC.

In **Pascal** I use the `initialization` section.

Here is a python example showing 2 styles of executing module level commands (unwrapped & wrapped).

I am curious to know if any cases exist whereby an existing module with unwrapped commands could not be modified to use the **wrapped** style (maybe something to do with global/nonlocal declarations?).

```
x = 1 # similar to c++ static variable init

#unwrapped
print(1 if x == 1 else 2)

#wrapped
def initialization():
    print(1 if x == 1 else 2)

initialization()
```

Comment: `if` and `while` are not "commands," they are statements. `print()` is not a "command," it is a function. There is no such thing as "command" in Python, and no "wrapped command," either.

Comment: For what it's worth, `def` is also an executable statement. So is `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in python, unless the module is really simple and is intended to do one thing and one thing only when run from the commandline, modules have a block that looks like this at the bottom:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run the main function here
    main()
```

This is so that when modules are imported, they don't start doing things when usually the intention is to use their functions, variables and classes.

I'm not sure if this answers your question; I'm not aware of any way to wrap statements that are in the top-level of the module aside from separating the ones that have to do with actions the module should perform out into related functions, and moving initialization code into a "main" function, and using the above block to trigger it when the module is run like `python yourmodule.py`.

Comment: I'm reverse engineering existing python code and putting into my flowchart tool, so I can split out the code no problem. I prefer to have statements inside a def because the flowchart gui can handle that. It doesn't cope with module level statements, only statements inside def.